# If a friend is willing to support my visit, can I use their details in a Canadan visa application?

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, canada, international-travel

I have been friends with someone in Canada for years. Can I use their statements and other details in my visa application as long as that person is willing to support me?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [a friend can write a letter of invitation](https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=207&top=17) and describe how they may support you during the trip and attach the relevant documents to prove their financial situation. Visiting a friend is a legitimate purpose to visit Canada.

If your visa application relies solely on the support of a friend, it is unlikely that it will be approved. The immigration officer reviewing your application will consider whether you will leave Canada by the end of your authorized stay. They will also consider factors such as your employment and financial situation in your home country, the reason for your visit to Canada, and any other connections you have to your home country. If you do not have sufficient financial resources on your own or do not have strong ties to your home country, the officer may conclude that you are likely to overstay or work illegally in Canada, which could result in your visa being denied.

Additionally, relationships with friends are generally considered weaker than those with family members. If your friend ends the relationship or withdraws financial support, it could affect your ability to stay in Canada. The officer may also be skeptical of your friendship if you are unable to provide a convincing explanation for your long-term relationship or the reason for your visit. In some cases, it could be seen as attempting to use a pretext for obtaining a Canadian visa rather than genuinely wanting to visit your friend. But of course, this all depends on the overall situation of your application and the justifications you can provide.

Comment: What Canadian authorities want is reasonable assurance that you will come visit and may be spend some money, then go home after your allotted time. Will you be able to prove that? That's the question. (From the answer I was writing)

Comment: Being able to show a prior travel history to an equivalent jurisdiction (eg Schengen) might help. But if your profile is eg ‘young/unmarried/never travelled/never met said friend in person/no savings’ an application  is highly unlikely to be successful. You could consider meeting your friend in a country you can both enter visa-free