# Proof of means financial support and proof of financial resource of supporter for Canadian visitor visa

Tags: visas, air-travel, customs-and-immigration, canada, international-travel

is letter of financial support from sponsor enough to fill as explanation for those two slots in Canada visitor visa application? [image]

Comment: I wouldn’t think so, no. Not unless the sponsor also provides evidence of their ability to fulfil the commitment, typically by means of bank statements and possibly proof of income source(s). See the answer to your previous question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178452/if-a-friend-is-willing-to-support-my-visit-can-i-use-their-details-in-a-canadan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a friend is willing to support my visit, can I use their details in a Canadan visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/178452/if-a-friend-is-willing-to-support-my-visit-can-i-use-their-details-in-a-canadan) This — your previous question — answers clearly that your friend's supporting documents (in addition to their assertion of financial responsibility for you) are necessary.